# Jenkins Jobs split in to multiple jobs based on module

Tags: maven, jenkins

Our structure is..
we have a product....under this product lot of subproducts....
productA------->productB,ProductC,ProductD
each product has their own POMs,including module info...
each product has a lot of modules ie...Product B has 10 modules and product C has 15 Modules..
each and every module has Pom.xml,,
as of now we are compiling from ProductA main Pom xml...
for each and every modification we have to compile our code...so that is the reason we want to compile only modified code...we want to split jenkins jobs as a productlevel.....can any one had done this past...let me know ur suggestions...

thanks

Comment: Use incremental build option in Jenkins in relationship with a multi-module. Furthermore can you show more details of your structure and how the pom file look like?

Comment: thanks for the reply.... say for example Main Pom contains---packaging folder,productaa,productb,product cfolders....each and every product has 20 modules and pom files,each and every module has pom files.....if we call ,main Pom only we will get packages....say for example my req is  one module got changed....we need to run and recompile only that module along with other 2 modules...any help its urgent...plzzzzzz